# Computation during analogRead on Arduino

Tags: arduino, i2c, spi, analog-digital-converter

The Arduino A/D converter takes about 0.1ms according to the manual.  Actually, my tests show that on an Uno I can execute about 7700 per second in a loop.

Unfortunately analogRead waits while the reading is being performed, making it difficult to get anything done.

I wish to interleave computation with a series of A/D conversions.  Is there any way of initiating the analogRead, then checking the timing and getting the completed value later?  If this needs to be low-level and non-portable to other versions, I can deal with that.

Looking for a solution that would allow sampling all the channels on an Arduino on a regular basis, then sending data via SPI or I2C.  I am willing to consider interrupts, but the sampling must remain extremely periodic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can start an ADC conversion without waiting for it to complete.  Instead of using `analogRead`, check out Nick Gammon's example [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/adc), in the "Read Without Blocking" section.

To achieve a regular sample rate, you can either:

1) Let it operate in free-running mode, where it takes samples as fast as it can, or

2) Use a timer ISR to start the ADC, or

3) Use `millis()` to start a conversion periodically (a common "polling" solution).  Be sure to step to the next conversion time by adding to the previously calculated conversion time, *not* by adding to the current time:

```
uint32_t last_conversion_time;

void setup()
{
   ...
  last_conversion_time = millis();
}

void loop()
{
  if (millis() - last_conversion_time >= ADC_INTERVAL) {
    <start a new conversion here>

    // Assume we got here as calculated, even if there
    //   were small delays
    last_conversion_time += ADC_INTERVAL;  // not millis()+ADC_INTERVAL!

    // If there are other delays in your program > ADC_INTERVAL,
    //   you won't get back in time, and your samples will not 
    //   be regularly-spaced.
```

Regardless of how you start the conversion periodically, you can either poll for completion *or* attach an ISR to be called when it is complete.

Be sure to use the `volatile` keyword for variables which are shared between the ISR and `loop`.